# Замыкания для параметров шаблонной функции в языке Swift 4

Tags: swift, функции, swift4

Есть шаблонная функция следующего вида:

```
func factory<T:Initializable>() -> ObjGenerator {

    return {

        return T(params: $0)
    }
}
```

`Initializable` представляет собой простенький протокол, обязывающий все классы его наследующие иметь конструктор следующего вида (приведу код протокола целиком):

```
protocol Initializable {

    init(params:Any)
}
```

`ObjGenerator` является синонимом для функции следующего вида:

```
typealias ObjGenerator = (Any) -> Initializable
```

Сейчас компилятор выдаёт ошибку для функции `factory`, мол тип `T` не используется в моей функции. Я понимаю, что сия помпезная конструкция выглядит не совсем адекватно, но ради интереса я всё-таки спрошу: действительно ли на данный момент в языке Swift 4 не поддерживаются подобного рода конструкции (что-то вроде замыканий для параметров шаблонной функции), или я просто где-то допустил синтаксическую ошибку?

Comment: А откуда компилятор узнает какой должен быть тип T? Ну и учитывая что на выходе получится Initializable, смысл этого?

Comment: @VAndrJ T - это класс, у которого должен быть конструктор, принимающий один аргумент типа Any. Когда я вызову данную функцию с параметром A, который наследует протокол Initializable, у меня T будет равен A. Swift не может захватить A как значение T и потом таскать её везде? Помню такое называлось раньше лексическим замыканием, но оно работало лишь для передаваемых в функцию значений, а настолько ли крут Swift, чтобы и типы так захватывать? Смысл данной конструкции сомнителен, я просто изучаю Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исходя из комментария некоторые моменты.

Данная функция не принимает параметров, поэтому T неизвестно. Если переписать, к примеру, таким образом:

```
func factory<T:Initializable>(for: T.Type) -> ObjGenerator {
    return {
        return T(params: $0)
    }
}
```

То ошибка исчезнет. Но. Так как `ObjGenerator = (Any) -> Initializable`, Вы получите в итоге `Ititializable`, а не нужный `T`.

Поэтому для примера перепишите до такого вида:

```
func factory<T:Initializable>(for: T.Type) -> (Any) -> T {
    return { T(params: $0) }
}
```

Тестируем:

```
class Test: Initializable {
    required init(params: Any) {
        print(params)
    }
}

let testFactory = factory(for: Test.self)
let testClass = testFactory("Test") // testClass тип Test
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вопрос больше практический чем теоретический, то Вы можете сделать расширение для `Initializable` и получать фабрику из него:

```
extension Initializable {
    static func factory() -> ObjGenerator {
        return self.init(params:)
    }
}
```

Использовать этот метод довольно просто:

```
let generator = Example.factory()
```

вместо

```
let generator = factory<Example>()
```

как было в Вашем варианте.

В качестве примера использована следующая структура:

```
struct Example: Initializable {
    init(params: Any) {}
}
```

Comment: Хороший ответ, но я хотел потренироваться в работе с шаблонами.